# Should I use 1 or 2 SQL queries for a list and a detailed view?

Tags: php, sql

Here is what bothers me: Is it more elegant (amount of data handled vs. number of queries) to use 1 or 2 queries.

let's use the following bogus structure:

```
CREATE TABLE myobj (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(64),
  color varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  price float,
  description text,
  dateofcreation varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to display a page with a list of records (object name, color, price)

```
List (name, color, price)
      apple, red,    5.00
      brick, orange, 1.00
      corn,  yellow, 2.00
```

and if `$_REQUEST['id']` is defined, I'd like to display the total amount of details (name, color, price, description, date of creation) for the record with the selected `id`

**Finally the question:**

Is it faster to use 1 query for the list view

```
SELECT name, color, price FROM myobj
```

followed with 1 query for the detailed view

```
SELECT * FROM myobj WHERE id=[id_provided]
```

or

1 query in total

```
SELECT * FROM myobj
```

and then save the values for the detailed view in PHP when the id of the current line of the result set matches the id provided in the http request?

I believe that 2 queries are more elegant but I wonder how efficient it is in terms of processing time (multiple db connections vs. heavy resultset including useless data)?

Comment: If you'll be obtaining the detailed view once per page, there's minimal cost in using two separate queries. If the user may be wanting several detailed views, it might be advantageous to get them all at once and show/hide them with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this really depends on many things, the number of rows and their size.

Two calls has significant overhead.  But depending on the size of the extra data that may or may not have more impact than the size the description field.  If there was no "text" description field then one call would clearly be faster.

But you said this was bogus -- so who can say about your actual query.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `TEXT` type on description field. Does OP *really* need to store more than 65,535 chars in one field?

Comment: it's rather close to my bogus one. In fact my records carry a TEXT field containing an HTML description of the object. This is actulaay the part that makes me wonder about process.time(1 data heavy query) vs process.time(1 list query limited to the light data + 1 query getting full detail for 1 record)

Comment: I used TEXT as it is data that is not significant at the operational level (i'm not going to do anything filtering on the description field) but that is required when trying to get details of an item.

Comment: It sounds like you want 2 queries to me because for any significant number of rows of html data it will be slower than a 2nd query.  (significant number of rows is probably something around 50-100 depending on the amount of HTML).

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much data you need.

Generally - less queries is better.

Lets say, there are "master" and "detail" tables.

If you have 100 "master" rows - you will need 100 queries to get "details" for them.

In cases like this - im getting all data with joins, then i build something like tree structure (array) to display it with "foreach" loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a user interface question.  Are you going to render the three columns first and then get the details?  If so, then you want to minimize the time to the rendering.  This says to use two queries.  The simpler query should be slightly faster, because it is returning less data.

If you are going to put all the details in before anyone sees them, then go with the second form.  That seems unlikely.

More importantly, I think it is bad practice to use `*` in queries of this sort.  You should explicitly include the list of columns for both queries.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at this. Your first suggestion for the list view is

```
   SELECT name, color, price FROM myobj
```

This is going to be a full table scan, just the same as a `SELECT * FROM myOBJ`
In other words, it's o(n)

Next, you have `SELECT * FROM myobj WHERE id=[id_provided]`
Since this field(id) is indexed, it's complexity is constant. It will just retrieve that row immediately.

However, it looks like you're going to be showing the detail for all of your items, and I'm assuming that you're going to be iterating through all of your rows and getting the detail for each. A constant retrieval for n records is going to be O(n).

If you're getting the detail for all the records, why not just `select *` once?

Comment: Your answer just looks at the big O of the question, not at the K (that is the constant big O ignores.  In reality, the big O can be an issue.